# How do I switch between windows in tmux with my own key shortcuts?

Tags: config, tmux, meta-key

I am using tmux version 3.1c. The command to switch to the previous window in tmux is the following:

`Ctrl-a + M + p`

However, my "meta-key" `M`, which I think should be `Alt Gr`or `Alt`, won't trigger (at some point I came across `ESC` as my meta-key but this is too confusing). Therefore, I want to easily replace switching to the previous window this with the command

`Ctrl-a + p`

And switching to the next window with

`Ctrl-a + n`

where `Ctrl-a` is my own prefix. How would this be possible? I was trying to change it inside my `.tmux.conf` file, but didn't got the expected result. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Great answer by punyakoti, to build on that.

You can re-select the active window by adding select-window after the swap.

```
bind-key -n C-S-Left swap-window -t -1\; select-window -t -1
bind-key -n C-S-Right swap-window -t +1\; select-window -t +1
```

Comment: Hi, prefer using a comment under the related answer when adding relevant but minor or incremental information to a post.

Answer (score 1):

I have this in my tmux.conf

```
#urxvt tab like window switching 
bind -n S-down new-window
bind -n S-left prev
bind -n S-right next
```

To switch the location of the tabs:

```
#Swapping Tmux windows
bind-key -n C-S-Left swap-window -t -1
bind-key -n C-S-Right swap-window -t +1
```